# How to connect multiple websites to one database in same server

Tags: mysql, database, sql-server

What would you do if you have one server and multiple websites in that server and you want to connect all of the websites to one MySQL database in the server?

I know it decreases the security but I want to know how can I do this?
And if it's not possible or it's hard to do in MySQL, is it possible in nginx ?

Comment: I know you can do this with SQL Server which you have the tag for sql-server I see but I'm not 100% sure with mysql. In any case, assuming your websites have a config file to point to the DB, you just point each site to it's own DB per each config file.

Comment: Are you using a specific CMS (such as WordPRess etc.)? As Koorosh's answer says, if you want all your sites on one database then it'd be easy to do if your tables were prefixed for which site they corresponded to - E.g. site 1 `s1_table1`, `s1_table2` and site 2 `s2_table` and site 3 `s3_table1`, `s3_table2` etc.

Comment: @AlexanderJones Its possible but how to do it might vary from what you are actually doing. Can you add some more info about what you are really trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to connect multiple websites to a single database , then you have to force websites to set `prefix` for their tables , just like `Wordpress`. some Control Panels like `CPanel` have this option and you can use that .

Answer (score 0):

When you say one server do you mean one database or one database server.

Assuming you have one server containing your database server you can have multiple databases on this database server.   There is no security risk with this each website would have its own password to its own database.   In a lot of instances it is preferable to have the database server separate from the web server for performance issues.

If you mean having one database and connecting two websites to the to the same database again this is also doable.  What I have seen done in the past is. You prefix the tables ws1_table one and ws2_table two.  I am not very familiar with MySql but in some database systems you can create users and give them access to only certain tables.  You could possibly create a user that only has access to ws1_ tables and another with access to only ws2_ tables this will ensure that they can not access each others data.